# Oracle SQL loader issue

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a table TABLE1 with columns R_ROW_ID, NAME, MARKS, TIME, NUMBER,LAST_UPD_TIME,USER_ID...
All column values are not null.

TABLE1 has unique index on column R_ROW_ID.

I have a file which has only NAME, MARKS data and load this data into TABLE1 using SQL Loader.

File1.txt has below data:

```
JOHN|83
DON|54
LONIS|91
```

How to populate ROLLNO with unique value , NUMBER with default value 0 and LAST_UPD_TIME with current timestamp

This file loading is one time and I  have created a sequencer SEQ as mentioned below:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ START WITH 90000 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Grant on this sequencer SEQ is:

```
  GRANT SELECT ON SEQ TO LOAD_USER;
```

This is the control file code I have written:

```
 LOAD DATA APPEND
 INTO TABLE TABLE1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
 TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (
   R_ROW_ID  "SEQ.NEXTVAL",
   NAME      CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:NAME),' ')",
   MARKS      CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:MARKS),' ')",
   TIME       CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:TIME),' ')",
   NUMBER    CONSTANT "0",
   LAST_UPD_TIME EXPRESSION "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)",
   USER_ID   CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:USER_ID),' ')"
   )
```

This is the error it is showing :

```
  SQL*Loader-951: Error calling once/load initialization
  ORA-02373: Error parsing insert statement for table TABLE1.
  ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Let me  know is there anything wrong in above one.

Is there any other way we can populate R_ROW_ID value (which should be unique) apart from using sequences ?

Comment: The error and the grant suggest you have created the sequence in a different schema; unclear which owns the table. You might just be able to specify the sequence owner as `"owner.SEQ.NEXTVAL"`. Or default it in the table definition instead.

Comment: I have added owner.SEQ.NEXTVAL and still its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, who knows what's wrong if you aren't telling the truth.

- You want to set `ROLLNO` to *something*, but that column doesn't exist in column list you specified in the 1st sentence.
- Then, you want to set column named `NUMBER` to *something else*; you probably don't, because `number` can't be column's name as it is keyword, reserved for **datatype** (true, there can be exceptions, but I doubt this is the issue here)

  ```
  SQL> create table test (number varchar2(10));
  create table test (number varchar2(10))
                     *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
  ```

Why did you create sequence in one schema (we don't know which one) and granted it to another user? Why don't you do *everything* in the same schema? Or did you just get a wrong idea that you should grant privilege on sequence you created to yourself?

Here's an example; see if it helps. Everything is being done in the same schema.

```
SQL> create table table1
  2    (r_row_id      number       not null,
  3     name          varchar2(10) not null,
  4     marks         number       not null,
  5     time          varchar2(10) not null,
  6     c_number      number       not null,
  7     last_upd_time timestamp    not null,
  8     user_id       varchar2(10) not null
  9    );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq start with 90000 increment by 1;

Sequence created.
```

Control file:

```
load data
infile *
replace
into table table1
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols
(
  name,
  marks,
  r_row_id      "seq.nextval",
  time          "nvl(:time, ' ')",
  c_number      constant "0",
  last_upd_time "systimestamp",
  user_id       "user"
)

begindata
JOHN|83
DON|54
LONIS|91
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test13.ctl log=test13.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 1 20:05:07 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

Table TABLE1:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test13.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

  R_ROW_ID NAME            MARKS TIME    C_NUMBER LAST_UPD_TIME              USER_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ---------- -------------------------- ----------
     90000 JOHN               83                0 01.05.2023 20:05:07:394000 SCOTT
     90001 DON                54                0 01.05.2023 20:05:07:394000 SCOTT
     90002 LONIS              91                0 01.05.2023 20:05:07:397000 SCOTT

SQL>
```

---

If you really are loading data using **another user**, then - in my example - "this" user is `scott` and he grants `select` on `seq` sequence to `mike`. Mike is doing the rest:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> grant select on seq to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mike/lion@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table table1
  2    (r_row_id      number       not null,
  3     name          varchar2(10) not null,
  4     marks         number       not null,
  5     time          varchar2(10) not null,
  6     c_number      number       not null,
  7     last_upd_time timestamp    not null,
  8     user_id       varchar2(10) not null
  9    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Control file; note modification for `r_row_id` (uppercase owner name!):

```
load data
infile *
replace
into table table1
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols
(
  name,
  marks,
  r_row_id      "SCOTT.seq.nextval",
  time          "nvl(:time, ' ')",
  c_number      constant "0",
  last_upd_time "systimestamp",
  user_id       "user"
)

begindata
JOHN|83
DON|54
LONIS|91
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr mike/lion@pdb1 control=test13.ctl log=test13.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 1 20:10:39 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

Table TABLE1:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test13.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From table1;

  R_ROW_ID NAME            MARKS TIME         C_NUMBER LAST_UPD_TIME              USER_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------- ----------
     90009 JOHN               83                     0 01.05.2023 20:10:39.885000 MIKE
     90010 DON                54                     0 01.05.2023 20:10:39.885000 MIKE
     90011 LONIS              91                     0 01.05.2023 20:10:39.911000 MIKE

SQL>
```

**Alternatively**, you could create a synonym for owner's sequence (still connected as `mike`):

```
SQL> create synonym seq for scott.seq;

Synonym created.
```

Then you don't have to modify the 1st control file I posted at all, and loading does the job:

```
SQL> $sqlldr mike/lion@pdb1 control=test13.ctl log=test13.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 1 20:13:15 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

Table TABLE1:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test13.log
for more information about the load.
```